# Hiding work items of Team A from Team B in Devops

Tags: tfs, devops

How can make sure work items of Team A is not visible to Team B and vice versa.
What I have done so far is

1. Made Teams A & B
   2.Added users in the relative teams
2. then in their Iterations &  Areas section
3. In Team A (areas section) set security for Team B --> work items not visible

but then it also hides from Team A

If I change security for work items in areas , (work items visibility to false for Team a , )it hides for both teams

Comment: Are people members of both teams? Are you setting read access to "Not set" or "Deny"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, when I set the `View work items in this node` permission as deny for Team B, the users in Team B will have no access to see the work items in Team A.

It could work as expected.

Here is my settings:

Team A security:

[image]

You need to check if the Team A and Team B has the same Team members. In this case, the permissions for the users will inherit the permissions of Deny by default.

For example: Team B in the Area for Team B.

[image]

**Update:**

Based on your latest comment, you could refer to the following settings:

To remove the admin from the team, you need to assign the team admin to **other users** in `Project Settings -> Teams -> Settings`.

[image]

1.Team A and Team B: you need to remove the current admin account.

[image]

No matter which team the current admin account is in, he cannot see all the work items.

2.Create additional Team(e.g. Team C). And the current  admin account to the new team. Grant all permission to the new team.

Comment: As Admin I m present in both teams , so when I hide it for team b ,like you have shown above , it gets hidden from me (admin ) too ,

Comment: This could be the root cause of this issue, you need to assign the admin to other users and remove the current account from one of the team. Then it could work fine.

Comment: Question 1 .
please correct me I am wrong 
Team A : Members--> Admin ,  users (1, 2, 3 ) 
Team B  Members-->  Admin , Users 4,5,6)

or 

Team A : Members--> Admin ,  users (1, 2, 3 ) 
Team B  Members-->   Users 4,5,6)


Question 2 . but as a admin I need to see all work items , how do i do that ?

Comment: and when I try to create a team without admin its gives error saying , "At least one administrator is required" also doesnt let me remove admin from current team

Comment: Based on your requirement, you need to remove the admin account from Team A and B at the same time. Then create a new team for the admin account and grant all permissions. Team A : Members-->  set user 1  as admin and remove the current admin  users (1, 2, 3 ) Team B Members-->set user 4 as admin  and remove the current admin Users 4,5,6) Team C : Admin

Comment: @RL. Please refer to my update about the steps to remove the team admin from the team A and B

Comment: If a group has an explicit Deny permission, then all users of that group are denied access. This overrides *all* other places "Allow" is set. "Not Set" can be read as "deny if not explicitly allowed elsewhere". "Deny" should be read as "deny even if explicitly allowed elsewhere"

Comment: Yes Daniel Mann's explanation is completely correct. Thank you  so much.

Comment: Thanks so very much @KevinLu-MSFT , finally got the solution.  :) , checking for various combinations, BTW, can you please tell me good source for learning Devops for Devops-newbie